# PySerial slowdown on read from Arduino

Tags: python, performance, arduino, pyserial

I'm attempting to write a handshaking procedure to allow my python program to automatically detect which port the Arduino is on. It works, however sometimes it runs extremely slow. Here's the problematic part of my code:

```
import serial, serial.tools.list_ports, time

portList = list(serial.toools.list_ports.comports())
conn = 0
while conn == 0:
    for port in portList:
        print(port[0])
        try:
            arduino = serial.Serial(port[0], 4800, timeout=.1)
            time.sleep(.2)
            sig = arduino.read()
            signum = int.from_bytes(sig, byteorder='little')
            if signum == 7:
                global comport
                comport = port[0]
                conn = 1
                break
        except:
            print('Could not read from ' + str(port[0]))
```

Essentially I have the Arduino constantly sending the arbitrary number '7' to the serial port. The python script scans each port for a 7 until it finds it. What's happening is that when it gets to the port that the Arduino is on, the code seemingly pauses executing for about 10 seconds at the `arduino = serial.Serial(...)` line right underneath the try statement. Since it's in a try loop, I know it's not throwing an error because it does eventually make it through. Is it just having trouble opening the port? How can this be fixed? I am on Python 3.4.3 and pySerial 2.7.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is more with how arduino does serial ... it waits for a serial connection to open then it does a bunch of setup you can see this with a relatively simple arduino sketch

```
int i;
void setup(){
   i=8;
   Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop(){
   Serial.print(i);
   Serial.print(",");
   i+=1;
}
```

and I think that you will always see 8 as the first number when you connect to the port ... I dont have an arduino on hand but I seem to recall seeing this behaviour

Comment: That could be it. I noticed that if I let the board sit plugged in for about 30 seconds before running my program it doesn't have this problem. But that doesn't explain why python would hang like that. All it's supposed to do is open the port and read one value. If the port were busy wouldn't that be caught by the try statement?

Comment: because its spitting out garbage startup strings ... that your program reads and interpret as not being 7 and starts the loop over again perhaps? are you sure its just hanging right there? (print something right at the top of the loop to see)

Comment: Yeah, I put about 6 print statements in there at one point. It never makes it to the time.sleep(.2) line. Like I said it makes it through eventually but it doesn't sit well with me, like something funky is going on behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

Just to check: Is the baudrate the same for both your Arduino and Python? Are there any other programs trying to access the Arduino?

Comment: Yep baudrate is the same and my script (a single .py file) is the only program accessing it.